# Logging Sequelize Migrations

Tags: sequelize.js

Just getting started with Sequelize and trying to get migrations working and would like to see what SQL the migrations are actually running against the DB.

I found a [github comment](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/610#issuecomment-69675229) which suggests how to pipe the logging to the debug module, but where do I put the "options".

```
options: {
  logging: debug('sequelize')
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Enable **"logging":true** in config conection data base (file **data_base.json**).

Example

```
{
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "agencias",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "timezone": "America/La_Paz",

    "migrationStorage": "sequelize",
    "migrationStorageTableName": "sequelize_migration",
    "logging":true,
    "pool": {
        "max": 15,
        "min": 0,
        "idle": 10000
    }
}
```

Execute in the project

```
sequelize db:migrate --migrations-path src/migrations --config data_base.json
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a few possible places to add this for sequelize. In the `.sequelizerc` if you want to see all logging for the sequelize CLI (See [documentation](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/master/README.md#options))   . If you just want to see it for specific queries in your up/down migrations, then you can pass it in for each queryInterface call as part of [options](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/).

For example, for `createTable` you can do:

```
queryInterface.createTable('myNewTable', {
        'my_column': Sequelize.STRING
    }, {
        logging: console.log
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Sequelize CLI passes the configuration defined in `config/config.js` to the sequelize constructor. Use the following to log SQL queries when running `sequelize db:migrate`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    development: {
        host: process.env.MSSQL_SERVER || 'localhost',
        username: process.env.MSSQL_USER || 'MSSQL_USER',
        password: process.env.MSSQL_USER_PASS || 'MSSQL_PASS',
        database: process.env.MSSQL_DB || 'DATABASE_NAME',
        dialect: process.env.DIALECT || 'mssql',
        logging: console.log
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `options` object is the fourth parameter to the Sequelize constructor (docs [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/)). `options.logging` defaults to `console.log`. I haven't used migrations much yet and so I'm not sure if this option is used then but it should be easy to test.

As a quick note, you'll usually pass many other options in this object to Sequelize as well, not just a logging function (see an example options object [here](https://github.com/cfogelberg/sequelize-playground/blob/master/tests/sequelize-config-pg.js#L13)).

I am not familiar with it, but the Sequelize documentation also suggests [Umzug](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug) as a library to use for execution and logging of migration tasks.

Comment: Thanks for that, but the problem is that when running the migrations, it's the command line tool that constructs the Sequalize object (not my code).

Comment: From code diving the CLI, it looks like Sequelize logging should be initialised to console.log when using the CLI. If it is not then setting logging: true in your configuration should initialise the Sequelize object this way. I base this on the Sequelize docs and https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/master/lib/helpers/config-helper.js#L102 If this doesn't work then can you please comment here with the value of the options variable (https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/master/lib/tasks/db.js#L290)?